# How to find general solution to $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2 -1/4)y = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had an exam yesterday, and this question has been bugging me. I was told to find the general solution to  $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2 -1/4)y = 0$ given that  $y = \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ is a solution. I must mention that the we were only taught a couple of methods to solve these types of DEs, such as the variation of constants and/or using the auxiliary equation. I did try both, but the expressions are quite complicated compared to the ones I see on various sites. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but any solution using nothing too advanced would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: There is a method that allows you to compute an unknown complementary solution from a known one. It involves something call a Wronskian. Does that help?

Comment: Also, upon seeing this problem, you should know that the general solution will have two terms. You should be instantly tempted to suspect that $\frac{\cos{(x)}}{\sqrt{x}}$ is also a solution. It seems like it should be but I haven't checked. Then with two different complementary solutions you should be able to able to build the general solution (after you notice that the equation is homogeneous).

Comment: For your curiosity, this is Bessel's equation of order $1/2$.

Comment: One might also be tempted to check how the DE would look like when expressed in the derivatives of $u(x)=\sqrt{x}y(x)$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Wronskian", we were only taught what I mentioned and some manipulations with non-constant equations which lead to $pyv''+ (2py'+qy)v'=0$ where, in my case, p is $x^2$, q is $x$, $y$ is the known solution, and $v$ is the variable constant that I should find to lead to another solution. I did do this out, and found that $v$ is equal to the integral of inverse sin by a constant, but I'm not sure what kind of identities you could possibly use to get that equal to the cos variant.

Answer (score 1):

@Chessnerd321 guessed that $y_2(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ is another solution. That is correct, see the following calculations.

We rewrite that Bessel differential equation of order $1/2$ as

$$y''+\dfrac{1}{x}y'+\left(x-\dfrac{1}{4x}\right)y=0.$$

Having known that it has a solution $y_1(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$. By a consequence of Abel formula, then the second solution can be get

\begin{align*}
y_2(x)&= y_1(x)\int\dfrac{e^{-\int\dfrac{dx}{x}}}{y_1^2(x)} dx\\
&= \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\int\dfrac{e^{-\int\dfrac{dx}{x}}}{\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}} dx=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\int\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}} dx=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\int\dfrac{1}{\sin^2 x} dx\\
&=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot (-\mathrm{cotan}\ x)= -\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}.
\end{align*}

Due to linearity, we can rechoose $y_2(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$. Consequently, all solutions of that Bessel equation are given by

$$y=C_1 \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}} + C_2 \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}.$$